# Split lines based on the position of a character

Tags: text-editing

consider this as a sample of a text file:

```
|60.05.33.14.61|
|03.22.32.23.44.20.45|
|25.17.03.20.24.05.61|
|60.24.40.35.14.25.16.01.03.61|
```

How can I delete all the initial `"|"`characters and not the end ones? (I do this kind of jobs mostly through scripting)

Or consider this:

```
13.03.33.61|20.24.05.61
13.25.17.03.20.24.05.61|33.13.61
04.42.35.38.23|35.25.24.42.19.25.10.19.61
```

How can I split these lines into two lines based on `"|"` position?

Comment: What operating system are you on? Is there anything you've tried yet which didn't work for you?

Comment: Deleting the initial `|` can be done with beginning of line `^` selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows then it can be done with PowerShell, see example below

```
$string = "one two three four"
$string.split(" ")

result:
one
two
three
four
```

Good thing is if you are using Windows 7 or above you already have it available.